# After using fadeOut() the message won't display again

Tags: jquery

After using a wrong password the message will be displayed but would fadeOut after certain time and if the wrong password is entered again, the message won't get displayed yet again. How should I go about getting the message for entering wrong password each time I enter the wrong password?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#new_pwd").click(function(){
        var current_pwd=$("#current_pwd").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"get",
            url:"../admin/check-pwd",
            data:{current_pwd:current_pwd},
            success:function(resp){
                if(resp=="false")
                {
                    //#chkpwd is span id
                    $('#chkpwd').html('<font color="red">Current Password is Incorrect</font>');
                    $('#chkpwd').fadeOut(3000);
                }
                else if(resp=="true")
                {
                    $('#chkpwd').html('<font color="green">Current Password is Correct</font>');
                }
            },
            error:function()
            {
                alert("Error");
            }
            
        })
    })
```

Comment: [`<font>` *"Do not use this element! Though once normalized in HTML 3.2, it was deprecated in HTML 4.01, at the same time as all elements related to styling only, then obsoleted in HTML5."*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font)

Comment: @epascarello Thanks fr the heads up man! Will keep this thing in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to `show()` the element since it'd been hidden from the DOM

```
if(resp=="false")
{
    //#chkpwd is span id
    $('#chkpwd').show().html('<font color="red">Current Password is Incorrect</font>');
    $('#chkpwd').fadeOut(3000);
}
```